# Create a dataframe of the column with the same name from multiple excel worksheets in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Assuming I have an excel file with 100s of sheets. In a toy example, the sheets are called = ['Apple', 'Farm', 'Kitchen', 'Napkin']

The sheets have multiple columns, but they all have a column called 'Sales'

I want a python dataframe with the `Sales` of all 4 products, by appending the name of the sheet to the word Sales

It will look like this:

```
Apple_Sales    Farm_Sales     Kitchen_Sales     Napkin_Sales

05               52               104               75
66              103               198               09
...              ..               ...               ..
```

So far, I am able to import the excel sheets into a dictionary of dataframes, but that is not what I am looking for

```
sales = r'D:/user/...../Sales.xlsx'

sal = pd.ExcelFile(Sales)
dictsdf = {sheets:sal.parse(sheets:sal) for sheets:sal in sal.sheet_names}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check the Snippet.

Steps Involved

1. Creating column names as Sheet names+Sales
2. Reading excel file and converting to dataframe
3. Storing values in list if **Sales** exist in dataframe.
4. Merging 1 and 3 to create key value pairs of sheet names and sales value as nested list.
5. Transposing nested list and converting to dataframe based on index value

My excel file looks like this

[image: Excel]

```
import pandas as pd
datadic = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
sheets=datadic.keys()
sheets=[i+"_"+'Sales' for i in sheets]

dictoframe=pd.Series(datadic).to_frame()
print(dictoframe.to_markdown())

"""
|         | 0                    |
|:--------|:---------------------|
| Apple   | a  b  c  Sales       |
|         | 0  1  2  3      4    |
|         | 1  5  6  7      8    |
| Farm    | d  Sales   e   f     |
|         | 0   9     10  11  12 |
|         | 1  13     14  15  16 |
| Kitchen | Sales   g   h   i    |
|         | 0     17  18  19  20 |
|         | 1     21  22  23  24 |
| Napkin  | j   k  Sales   l     |
|         | 0  25  26     27  28 |
|         | 1  29  30     31  32 |
"""

listofsales=[i['Sales'].tolist() for i in dictoframe[0] if('Sales' in i)]        
finaldic=dict(zip(sheets,listofsales))
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(finaldic,orient='index').transpose()
print(df)

"""
   Apple_Sales  Farm_Sales  Kitchen_Sales  Napkin_Sales
0            4          10             17            27
1            8          14             21            31
"""
```